# KMP algorithm application

Tags: algorithm

when the kmp algorithm is applied on a pattern during preprocessing does the  array created starts with the value 0 or 1 if i starts with 1? I mean  the element if the pattern gets a value of 0 or 1 in the preprocessed array?

Comment: Normally arrays are zero indexed meaning they start at zero. I don't know about this algorithm specifically, but I would assume it follows the convention of being zero indexed.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is indexed from 1, The first value will be 1,

whereas if it is indexed from 0, the first value will be 0.

I hope, this is what you are asking for. :)

Answer (score -1):

It starts with 1st index, value at 0th index is always kept zero.

> PSEDU CODE

KMP-PREFIX-ARRAY(PATTERN)

```
j<- 0 ; i <- 1;
NEWARRAY[PATTERN.length]
while i < PATTERN.length
         if PATTERN[i] = PATTERN[j]
              j <- j + 1;
              NEWARRAY [i] <- j;
              i <- i + 1;
         else
             if j = 0
                 NEWARRAY[i] <- j;
             else
                 J = NEWARRAY[j - 1];
   return NEWARRAY;
```